# Using UI Thread when running WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, dispatcher

I am attempting to use WCF to test my program. The problem I am running into is when I call methods through WCF, they are run on a worker thread. The method that I am trying to test needs to run in the UI thread or I get the following error:

> DragDrop registration did not succeed. Current thread must be set to 
>   single thread apartment STA mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure
>   that your main  function has  STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

My main function in my program has the STAThread attribute.  I was able to get it to work by doing the following inside of my method.

```
public void MyMethod(){
if (InvokeRequired) {
   Invoke(new MethodInvoker(MyMethod));
   return;
   }
   //Do stuff
}
```

I don't want to have to make this change for every method inside of my program. Is there a way to get WCF to run the methods on the UI thread everytime?

Comment: Clear a few things up: this is about self-hosting in a WinForms/WPF app? You really do drag-and-drop through WCF?

Comment: My program uses WinForms. The WCF is not "part" of my program. I am using WCF to test my program, by making calls to methods. I then call another method to verify that the previous method worked. For example, I first call AddPerson. The second call would be IsPersonInList, which would return a bool.

Comment: We are currently doing unit tests and coded UI tests, but have been asked to use WCF for further testing.

Comment: Well, the core answer is below. Maybe you can use WCF to steer the GUI tests, I don't know.

Comment: Using UI Thread when running... WTF? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get WCF to run the methods on the UI thread everytime?

No. Even when you config WCF to run as SingleThreaded it will still be a server thread.